# MySQL join statement

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables:

countries table

```
country|lang1|lang2|lang3|lang4
Canada |1    |2    |NULL |NULL
US     |1    |NULL |NULL |NULL
```

and

languages table

```
id|language
1 |English
2 |French
```

I want to return the values for both rows in my countries table, with the language names.

How do I do that?

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM en_countries LEFT JOIN all_languages 
ON (all_languages.id = en_countries.lang1 AND all_languages.id = en_countries.lang2)
```

but that doesn't give me the language names.  How do I do this?

If someone could give me this in Active Record format, that would be a bonus.  I'm doing this for CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is with `(all_languages.id = en_countries.lang1 AND all_languages.id = en_countries.lang2)`

rather try

```
SELECT * FROM en_countries LEFT JOIN all_languages 
ON (all_languages.id = en_countries.lang1 OR all_languages.id = en_countries.lang2)
```

The 'and' implies that one language should be the first and second language of a country, replacing it with 'or' may do the trick

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  This works fine, but I prefer the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm getting your question right, but it sounds like you should be using an `inner join` rather than a `left join`. [See this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

---

```
select country.*
from en_countries as country
join all_languages as lang1
on lang1.id = country.lang1
join all_languages as lang2
on lang2.id = country.lang2
-- optionally:
where lang1.id = ?
and lang2.id = ?
```

Comment: INNER JOIN doesn't return any rows from the DB

Comment: Well, you'd need two joins. Give me a sec, I'll update my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you use `AND` that means that only records with the same lang1 equals lang2 will joined. I believe you need something like :

```
SELECT c.*, l1.language as lang1_name, l2.language as lang2_name  
FROM en_countries c
LEFT JOIN all_languages l1 ON (l1.id = c1.lang1)
LEFT JOIN all_languages l2 ON (l2.id = c1.lang2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from all_languages two times

```
SELECT en_countries.country, t1.language as lang1, t2.language as lang2    FROM en_countries    
JOIN all_languages AS t1 ON t1.id = en_countries.lang1 
JOIN all_languages AS t2 ON t2.id = en_countries.lang2
```

Then I believe you access in php as $row->lang1

Comment: This works too, but returns a single row, which is more ideal.  How do I access t1 and t2 in my PHP.  In a foreach loop, would it be $row->t1?

Comment: I don't use PHP but I think you need to give the column a unique name. See Edit